# Use one sql table wp_posts and wp_postmeta for multisite wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, triggers, multisite

i have multi site wordpress used for news and have the same database the difference is in the prefix

**SITE 1 : wp_posts 

SITE 2 : wp_2_posts**

for specific needs i want all posts or custom posts be saved just in one table wp_post.
like that if any posts be add in **SITE 1** will be dynamically add in the **SITE 2**

Comment: Hi there, did you find my answer useful?

Comment: i'm still confused where i use this code Before your answer i try to work with other solution is Trigger code is like that 
        `create trigger update_post_content<br>
            after insert
            on wp_posts
            for each row<br>
        BEGIN<br>
                IF NEW.post_type = 'newsletter' then
                INSERT INTO wp_2_posts (ID, post_author, post_date, ...........)<br>
                  value (NEW.ID, NEW.post_author, NEW.post_date, ............);<br>

           END IF;<br>
          END //`<br>
get_default_post_to_edit( )

Comment: but when i use this solution and i try to creat campane '' custom post'' i find error 
Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Comment: You don't need to insert the post into `wp_2_posts`. You can read them all from `wp_posts` if you use `switch_to_blog(1)` before you retrieve them

Answer (score 0):

Save your posts in site 1.

Then in site 2, use `switch_to_blog(1)` before you query for posts. This way your query queries from site 1 (`wp_posts`).

After you're finished call `restore_current_blog()`.

```php
switch_to_blog(1);

$query = new WP_Query();

// etc ...

restore_current_blog();
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/ for more information.

Comment: Hi 
when i try to applique this solution in my website i'm face fatal error in php is  **call to undefined function switch_to_blog()** 
the solution of this error is create function with condition multisite must be defined
`if(is_multisite()){ // variable defined multisite in site 2 is false <br>
switch_to_blog(1);
}`
but when i defined  multisite in wp_config of site 2 the site 2 is get down because  **of error establishing a database connection**

Comment: Okay so your WordPress installation isn't a multisite? That means it are two separate WordPress installations using the same database? That's highly unusual!!! Also the title of your question should be different. You shouldn't call it a multisite but "multiple sites". Multisite will get people confused

Comment: No my wordpress installation is multisite and i use the same database for that but how i make multisite defined in the site 2 ?

Comment: If it's a multisite there's only one `wp-config.php` there you should define it.